# Jtable.org custom buttons to Update a field in mysql, onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, function, jtable

I'm using Jtable (jtable.org), and now I added 2 custom buttons on each row, that i need to update that row value inside mysql. The buttons are to set approval or denial to that row, onclick. So I have a green button and a red one.

When the specific user clicks the "green button", it must update the "approval" field inside mysql to value "yes" and if clicks the "red button", sets it to "no".

So far, my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Prepare jTable
    $('#pretencao_ferias').jtable({
        title: 'Pretenção de Férias / Licença Prêmio',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'data_inicio ASC, nome ASC',
        //editinline:{enable:true},
        selecting: false, //Enable selecting
        //multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        //selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column

        actions: {
            listAction: 'Acao.php?action=list',
            createAction: 'Acao.php?action=create',
            updateAction: 'Acao.php?action=update',
            deleteAction: 'Acao.php?action=delete'
        },

        customButtons: {
            items: [
                {
                    icon: 'images/green_16x16.png', // used ../default-16x16.png by default
                    text: 'Aprovar',
                    click: function(record) {
                        alert(record);
                    },
                    position: 'left' // right by default
                },

                {
                    icon: 'images/red_16x16.png', // used ../default-16x16.png by default
                    text: 'Negar',
                    click: function(record) {
                        alert(record);
                    },
                    position: 'left' // right by default
                }
            ]
        },
        toolbar:{               
            items: [{
                icon: 'images/pdf.jpg',
                text: 'Criar PDF',
                click: function () {
                    window.open('cria_pdf.php');
                }
            }]},
            fields: {
                id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                ...
```

**I don't know javascript enough to create a function to "click:" . And it's for that I need your help with the specific fields bellow:**

```
customButtons: {
    items: [
        {
            icon: 'images/green_16x16.png', // used ../default-16x16.png by default
            text: 'Aprovar',
            click: function(record) {
                alert(record);
            },
            position: 'left' // right by default
        },

        {
            icon: 'images/red_16x16.png', // used ../default-16x16.png by default
            text: 'Negar',
            click: function(record) {
                alert(record);
            },
            position: 'left' // right by default
        }
    ]
},
```

Where the value of "aproved" must be

```
<CENTER><img src="images/redondo_verde.png" alt="Aguardando Aprovação"></CENTER>
```

And the denial

```
<CENTER><img src="images/redondo_vermelho.png" alt="Aguardando Aprovação"></CENTER>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your click functions you will need to do a few things.

1. Make an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to your action page to update the database.
   The url for the call would look something like:

   "Acao.php?action=approve&id="+record.whatever_your_unique_id_is

   "Acao.php?action=deny&id="+record.whatever_your_unique_id_is
2. In your Acao.php page you will need to write handlers for "approve" and "deny". 
   These will look similar to the "update" action except they will only update the approve or deny column in the database.
3. The ajax call you make will have a "success" callback and you will use that to modify the icons images so that they show approved or denied.
4. Finally you will need to ensure that you put the correct image in for the icons when the records are loaded so that ones that are already approved or denied reflect that when the page loads.

   $.ajax({ 
       url: 'recurring_cost_action.php',
      type: "GET",
     error: function()
              {
                alert('An error has occurred! Please try again.');
              },
      data: {
                action: "approve", id: record.main_id 
              },
   success: function(data)
              {
                  //This is Where You Want to do step 3
              }
          });

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you. But, i'm an analphabet in javascript, i don't know how to do the 1st and 3rd steps.

the step 2, i understand, i'll do something like

    if($_GET["action"] == "approve") {...}

Comment: i added a simple ajax example. sorry for formatting, the code formatting wouldn't work for some reason. if you go into my answer to edit the code is more readable.

Comment: click: $.ajax({ url: 'recurring_cost_action.php', 
type: "GET", 
error: function() { alert('An error has occurred! Please try again.'); }, 
data: {
action: "approve", id: record.main_id }, 
success: function(data) { //This is Where You Want to do step 3 } });
            },

This ???

Comment: yup that looks right. what you want in step 3 is to do something to replace the images in the icon on that row

Comment: oh replace record.main_id with your first key column name in the fields list. main_id should be replaced with the name of your key column

Comment: Nathan, i did this:

    click: function DoAction( id )
{
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "Acao.php",
         data: "action=aprovacao&situacao=aprovado"
    });
},    

And 99% worked for me ... but i don't know how i can get the row "id" field ...

Comment: The only problem now is how to i get the ID field and pass it too if i can solve this , will work i suppose

Comment: record has all the fields in it. so record.field_name is the values. it depends what your field names are.

Comment: the ID field name is ID .... i'd tried  data: "action=aprovacao&situacao=aprovado&id="+id

but no success

Comment: click: function(record) {
                alert(record.id); //is the id
            },

Comment: I'd tried : "action=aprovacao&situacao=aprovado&id="+record.id 

Where ID is the name of the field, nothing... got an error on Debbuger: "uncaught referenceError: record is not defined"

Comment: Forget it, i've found my error:

function () , but the right is function (record)

Thank you ALOT!

Comment: Need only one thing more... it worked, i've updated the DB, but i need to reload the table to show the new value... can you help with this too ?

Comment: there is an onRecordsLoaded event that you can call after your fields section